# using \textheight and \baselineskip in scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, lengths

I want to tell `nomencl` to print all items on a single page.

If I use `\documentclass{article}` my code to let LaTeX compute the right length for `nomitemsep` itself works fine.

But if I use `\documentclass{scrartcl}` the computation of `nomitemsep` returns a wrong value (a value, that is too small).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

%\setlength{\nomitemsep}{\textheight / (27 * \baselineskip)}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{0.12cm}

\begin{document}

%TODO this are 28 items
\nomenclature{$\alpha$}{}
\nomenclature{$\beta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\gamma$}{}
\nomenclature{$\delta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\epsilon$}{}
\nomenclature{$\zeta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\eta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\theta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\iota$}{}
\nomenclature{$\kappa$}{}
\nomenclature{$\lambda$}{}
\nomenclature{$\mu$}{}
\nomenclature{$\nu$}{}
\nomenclature{$\xi$}{}
\nomenclature{$o$}{}
\nomenclature{$\pi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\rho$}{}
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{}
\nomenclature{$\tau$}{}
\nomenclature{$\upsilon$}{}
\nomenclature{$\phi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\chi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\psi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\omega$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Gamma$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Delta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Theta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Lambda$}{}

\printnomenclature


\end{document}
```

Comment: The ratio between two dimensions is not a dimension; you possibly want to do `\dimexpr(\textheight-27\baselineskip)/27\relax`, but you're not taking into account the header.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do operations on lengths like that. However, the solution avoids counting the items, so long as they can fit in a page:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\makenomenclature

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{\fill}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\vspace{-\topsep}}% remove the space inserted by \endlist

\begin{document}
x % to get the nomenclature

\nomenclature{$\alpha$}{}
\nomenclature{$\beta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\gamma$}{}
\nomenclature{$\delta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\epsilon$}{}
\nomenclature{$\zeta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\eta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\theta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\iota$}{}
\nomenclature{$\kappa$}{}
\nomenclature{$\lambda$}{}
\nomenclature{$\mu$}{}
\nomenclature{$\nu$}{}
\nomenclature{$\xi$}{}
\nomenclature{$o$}{}
\nomenclature{$\pi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\rho$}{}
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{}
\nomenclature{$\tau$}{}
\nomenclature{$\upsilon$}{}
\nomenclature{$\phi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\chi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\psi$}{}
\nomenclature{$\omega$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Gamma$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Delta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Theta$}{}
\nomenclature{$\Lambda$}{}

\clearpage % go to a fresh page
\begingroup % limit the effect of \flushbottom
\flushbottom
\printnomenclature
\clearpage % eject the page
\endgroup % end the group

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there also an easy solution to flush the items on two pages? e. g. if I have 50 items, or if I just want to have a larger whitespace

Comment: @Ben It should work out of the box

Comment: If I add six more items they are all (34) still printed on a single page (very closely to each other) If I add seven, LaTeX decides to print the last two on a second page (one at the bottom and one at the top) -> 33:2 maybe something like 16:19 would be nicer (note the space that is used by "Nomenclature")

Comment: @Ben Of course the decision should be made when the text is in final form; you can then do `\setlength{\nomitemsep}{??pt plus 1fill}` (experiment with the number to change `??` into.

Comment: So I guess the "highest" possible number should be chosen for `??`? `?? = 17` splits it to 17:17. What exactly does `plus 1fill` do?

Comment: @Ben With `5pt plus 1fill` you ensure at least 5pt space between entries, but the space is allowed to stretch as much as needed. I should say the idea is not really appealing to me: if you find that only a few entries end up in the final page, do `\setlength{\nomitemsep}{6pt plus 2pt}` (or whatever seems necessary) and forget about filling the last page.

Comment: I do not see any difference between `\setlength{\nomitemsep}{6pt plus 2pt}` and just `\setlength{\nomitemsep}{6pt}` or `5pt plus 2pt` and just `5pt` or `5.5pt plus 2pt` and just `5.5pt`. The first page is always filled